# Mercurial server running multiple repositories

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I'm using TortoiseHg, and I want to run it as a server. I've been able to run the server, pointing it to the root of the repository I've chosen.

- `http://192.168.1.64:8000` points to `c:\myproject`

I'm looking for a way to have a folder `C:\projects`, with multiple repositories inside, pointing my Hg server to that folder, and i would access my repositories like:

- `http://192.168.1.64:8000/project1` points to `c:\projects\project1`
- `http://192.168.1.64:8000/project2` points to `c:\projects\project2`

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you need to set up a full web server, either IIS or Apache, and host hgweb, the Python cgi script that Mercurial comes with (you may have to download the source for this.)

See [Publishing Repositories with hgwebdir.cgi](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HgWebDirStepByStep) for more details.

Comment: This tuturial, helped me a lot:
http://makinggames.ca/dev/version-control-mercurial-apache-tortoisehg/

Comment: I like using ISAPI over cgi. A good tutorial is here: http://www.firegarden.com/software/hosting-mercurial-repo-iis7-windows-server-2008r2-x64-python-isapi-cgi

Comment: The link is broken for both the selenic.com site as well as the firegarden site from Jason Down.  Any updates on those?

Comment: I found the updated one for hgwebdir.cgi here:  https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HgWebDirStepByStep

Answer (score 12):

While using a full web server for repo hosting, as suggested by Lasse, is a good idea, nothing prevents you from serving multiple repositories using `hg serve`.

Here's my `hgweb.config` file:

```
[paths]
project-a = C:/hg/project-a/
library-b = C:/hg/library-b/
```

I start `hg serve` with this command:

```
hg serve --address 127.0.0.1 --port 8000 --webdir-conf C:/hg/hgweb.config --encoding utf8
```

Comment: thanks, that is certainly a great solution, now i have gone through all the headaches of setting up a server though. :)

Answer (score 2):

you should edit the hgweb.config file, as it is by default of view like:

```
[web]
style = gitweb

[collections]
<br>
/mercurial/collections = /mercurial/collections
```

so, assume that record as first /mercurial/collections is the identifier name whereas second (right side from equals sign) stands for physical path of repo.

for example, I have made it like:

```
[web]
style = gitweb

[collections]
myrepo1 = /mercurial/repositories/hang_over
myrepo2 = /mercurial/repositories/first_repo
myrepo3 = /mercurial/repositories/javaforever
```

Im making this under linux ubuntu distribution version.

anyways, here mercurial directory is in my root directory and I'm pointing from it to /mercurial/repositories.

hope it helped you.

Sincerely.